# "If" in OnCreate fails

Tags: android, oncreate

In my

> onCreate

I am setting

```
myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("sentString");
```

and after that

```
if (myString == "test") {...}
```

fails to execute...

even though afterwards

```
btnTest.setText(myString);
```

Works

What is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always use String.equals() when comparing strings.  The == will just compare the reference.

Example: instead of

```
if (myString == "test") {...}
```

use:

```
if (myString.equals("test")) {...}
```